# Blank email, no error when sending email with PHP

Tags: php, html, email, email-attachments

My code is not producing email and just showing a blank screen. I have compared the output to other email and comparing headers seems that no problem is there.

#### Code:

```
    function SendEmail($pemail, $pfirst, $plast, $add1,$add2,$pcode) {
        
    $messageplain="Test here is a test ";
    $messagehtml = "<p> A test is here </p>";
    $myemail = "coconut@gmail.com";         //<-----Put Your email address here. ----->
    $test_email="blah@hotmail.co.uk";
    $crlf = "\r\n";
        
        echo "<br /><b>Emailing ..." . $pemail. "</b><br />";
        
        $to = $test_email;
         //$to = "$first_name $lasyt_name<$pemail";
        $email_subject = "With urgent regard your pledge to support Speckled Wood TQ834112";
        // Add in our primary content boundary, and mime type specification - for inline attachment image:
        $sep = sha1(date('r', time()));
        $headers = array
        (
    //        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit',
    //      'In-Reply-To:'.$sep.'@speckledwood.org.uk',
            'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="-PHP-'.$sep.'"',
    //      'To: ' . $to,
            'From: Friends of Speckled Wood Management Trust <'.$myemail.'>',
            'Reply-To: Friends of Speckled Wood Management Trust <'.$myemail.'>',
            'MIME-Version: 1.0',
    //        'Date: ' . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']),
            'Message-ID: <' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . '@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '>',
            'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion(),
    //      'Return-Path: Friends of Speckled Wood Management Trust <'.$myemail.'>',
    //        'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
        );
        $image="../assets/foswmt.jpg";
        if(!file_exists($image)) die("ERROR #000001: Fatal Error could not locate email attachment image {$image}");
        $attachment = file_get_contents($image);
        $encoded = base64_encode($attachment);
        $attached = chunk_split($encoded);
      
        $email_body = array
          (
            '---PHP-'.$sep.'',
            'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="-PHP-'.$sep.'"',
            ' ',
            ' ',
            '---PHP-'.$sep.'',
            'Content Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-2"',
    //      'Content-Disposition: inline',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable',
            ' ',
            $messageplain,
            ' ',
            ' ',
            '---PHP-'.$sep.'',
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-2"',
    //      'Content-Disposition: inline',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable',
            ' ',
            '<html><body>',
            '<p><centre><img src="cid:PHP-CID-'.$sep.'" alt="foswmt group" height="200" width="200"></centre></p>',
            $messagehtml,
            '</body></html>',
            '---PHP-'.$sep.'--',
            ' ',
            '---PHP-'.$sep.'',
            'Content Type: image/jpeg;',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64',
            'Contect-ID: <PHP-CID-'.$sep.'>',
            'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "logo.jpg"',
            $attached,
            '---PHP-'.$sep.'--'
            
        );
        
        $email_subject = $pfirst. " ". $plast . " we wish you to make a pledge with urgent regard to Speckled Wood TQ834112";
        // $headers .= "Return-Path: http://www.speckledwood.org.uk/donate\r\n";
        $sent = mail($to,$email_subject,implode($crlf, $email_body),implode($crlf, $headers));
        
        //echo( "<br /><br />header: <br />" . $headers."body: <br />". $email_body .  "<br /><br />");
    }
    ?>
    
    <?php
                $count=0;
                $countemail=0;
                
                $conlivedata = mysql_pconnect("localhost","user","password");
                    if (!$conlivedata) {
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                $con = mysql_pconnect("instance41919.db.xeround.com:6326","user","password");
                if (!$con) {
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                mysql_select_db("csv_db", $con)or die("A MySQL error has occurred.Your Query: Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
                
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE EmailAddr <> ' ' ORDER BY `EmailAddr`", $con) or die("<br/>A MySQL Query error has occurred.Your Query: Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
                
                $total = (mysql_result($result, 0));
                ob_end_flush();
                $i=0;
        
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $Email = $row['EmailAddr'];
                    $i++;
                    if ($Email != NULL ){
                        mysql_select_db("foswood_db", $conlivedata) or die("<br/>A MySQL error has occurred Slecting Database.<br />Your Query: <br/> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
                        $liveresult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pledges WHERE EmailAddr = '$Email'", $conlivedata) or die("<br/>A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: <br /> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
                        if(mysql_result($liveresult, 0) ) {
                            $count +=1;
                        } else {
                            $countemail+= 1;
                            echo $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "       at : " . $row['street_address']. "," . $row['street_address2']. "-" . $row['street_address']. "." . $row['postcode_address'];
                            SendEmail($row['EmailAddr'],$row['first_name'],$row['last_name'] ,$row['street_address'],$row['street_address2'],$row['street_address'],$row['postcode_address']);
                            
                                    // Calculate the percentation
                            $percent = intval(($i/$total) * 100)."%";
                            // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
                            echo '<script language="javascript">
                            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#880000;\">&nbsp;</div>";
                            document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
                            </script>';
                         
                            // This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
                            echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);
                         
                            // Send output to browser immediately
                            flush();
            
                            
                            
                        }
                        mysql_select_db("csv_db", $con) or die("<br/>A MySQL error has occurred Slecting Database.<br />Your Query: <br /> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
                    }
                    echo "<br />";
                }
                // Tell user that the process is completed
                echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';
        
                echo "<br/><br/><b/>Totals:  " .$countemail." users where emailed . ". $count . " users have pledged.</b/>";
                mysql_close($con);
                mysql_close($conlivedata);
            
    ?>
```

#### Email Output:

```
    x-store-info:J++/JTCzmObr++wNraA4Pa4f5Xd6uens1Lp3iK0Ye5aEjPdIeMl+dLztxnwvfAro8TnNo6oBhGA7L/DjzgZOx0ppu40FIoBOCmeUFoon2LHkqEz1HUPWZD8509hWmnOI6C5Vv2MwPthOB2arSXfcxQ==
    Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is 213.146.180.236) smtp.mailfrom=anonymous@plesk1.scl.co.uk; dkim=none header.d=gmail.com; x-hmca=none
    X-SID-PRA: blah@gmail.com
    X-AUTH-Result: NONE
    X-SID-Result: NONE
    X-Message-Status: n:n
    X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTE7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0w
    X-Message-Info: aKlYzGSc+Lm8gD7dwUXYSRNR5LLYBBvh97q7glDSvulIBZntxAmNOdzNstRoIcJdOm3yFA8mQDHaJB3blBVcKgwYxogtqVPN3HhKvyIhWpalwIvoeAaTyHiqoDqbM88C293BzBRm/nMwFkTrFlu4qMmHYqUBkcOD
    Received: from plesk1.scl.co.uk ([213.146.180.236]) by BAY0-MC3-F1.Bay0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
         Sun, 24 Mar 2013 11:37:33 -0700
    Received: (qmail 8872 invoked by uid 33); 24 Mar 2013 18:37:32 +0000
    Date: 24 Mar 2013 18:37:32 +0000
    To: blah@hotmail.co.uk
    Subject: Adam Britton we wish you to make a pledge with urgent regard to Speckled Wood TQ834112
    X-PHP-Originating-Script: 10323:EmailUsers2.php
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="-PHP-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191"
    From: Blah <blah@gmail.com>
    Reply-To: Blah <blah@gmail.com>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Message-ID: <1364150249e01977f5edd650baa7b5e672a1d5bc96@www.speckledwood.org.uk>
    X-Mailer: PHP v5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10
    Return-Path: anonymous@plesk1.scl.co.uk
    X-OriginalArrivalTime: 24 Mar 2013 18:37:33.0432 (UTC) FILETIME=[A6013F80:01CE28BE]
    
    ---PHP-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="-PHP-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191"
     
     
    ---PHP-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191
    Content Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-2"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
     
    Test here is a test 
     
     
    ---PHP-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-2"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
     
    <html><body>
    <p><centre><img src="cid:PHP-CID-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191" alt="foswmt group" height="200" width="200"></centre></p>
    <p> A test is here </p>
    </body></html>
     
    ---PHP-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191--
    ---PHP-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191
    Content Type: image/jpeg;
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Contect-ID: <PHP-CID-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191>
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "logo.jpg"
    /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/7RO4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNA+0AAAAAABAASAAAAAEA
    AgBIAAAAAQACOEJJTQQNAAAAAAAEAAAAHjhCSU0EGQAAAAAABAAAAB44QklNA/MAAAAAAAkAAAAA
    AAAAAAEAOEJJTQQKAAAAAAABAAA4QklNJxAAAAAAAAoAAQAAAAAAAAACOEJJTQP1AAAAAABIAC9m
    ZgABAGxmZgAGAAAAAAABAC9mZgABAKGZmgAGAAAAAAABADIAAAABAFoAAAAGAAAAAAABADUAAAAB
    AC0AAAAGAAAAAAABOEJJTQP4AAAAAABwAAD/////////////////////////////A+gAAAAA////
    
    etc...
    ---PHP-12e6e3f21ec76200f42baff8c05e6cbbe0fbe191--
```

Comment: blank screen means to look in your error log

Comment: in my error log? There is no code errors shown in my editor?

Comment: That's because you haven't enabled error reporting on screen.

Comment: Um the error is only with the email not the php. Although this is useful to know. I have an editor that checks syntax of code. If someone could tell me what is wrong with the email what is produced I could change my code to get the affect but the output looks good and have no idea whats wrong and stopping it showing in outlook in my hotmail account in a web page

Comment: Hoping someone can come up with an answer as still not any the wiser email looks good if someone can tell me whats wrong with the email I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you what the problem with your code is, but my general advice would be using a library like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead. It takes the pain out of building multi-part and attachment E-Mails.

Other than that, what you need to do first is basic debugging: check the program flow step by step, output the variable contents, until you find the reason why the text ends up blank. That'll give you a much more specific question to ask.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. the code  producing no errors and giving me exactly what it should . the problem is that the email it is producing is not displaying in outlook correctly. I have tried removing adding headers but nothing seems to work . I have a similar piece of code that produces the same file and this works . Even changing this file to the same as the working one will not produce a working email. The only difference is that I am using array to hold header and body. and imploding this on the message send line.   on ,my other code i am using <<<EOBODY .... EOBODY; to collect the body and headers.

Comment: Ah, shouldn't there be \r\n\r\n after mime headers with no space in between?

Comment: @Martin fair enough, I didn't realize it was a purely client side problem. I'm sure the code could be made to work with Outlook as well, but I'm not sure whether it's worth the effort - hence my recommendation to go for a library that doe the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Am using $crlf = "\r\n" here with implode($crlf, $headers) which puts a \r\n after each line. I can use a different solution as with mailchimp as I have too many records.  why would i need \r\n\r\n is this after the end of the mime headers. I have just added this but get the same result of a blank email.

Comment: Closed again Gosh this system is crazy

Comment: What a rubbish system that closes posts without allowing an answer to be put up. I have to ask who is running this site!

 I found a solution to my problem by reverting back to some of my old code I could not use the array an implode to populate the mail( line . This i think gave wrong information when constructing email